# Reading MIDI Events, Messages from a chunk of a midi file using NAudio

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

I'm a novice in MIDI things, so please don't be cruel with me :)
I have an Yamaha midi file which contains some Sections, like Midi Header Section, CASM Section, OTS Section, MDB Section and MH Section.
I want to give some attention to OTS Section. OTS section contains ID = 4 bytes, Data Length = 4 bytes, and Data. Data is a midi file structure chunk but it not contains notes, only settings like channels used, and settings for each channel, like MSB-LSB-PC of used voice, Volumes, Harmony and so on.
The question is how do I retrieve the channels used, how do I retrieve the MSB-LSB-PC pair of voice/drum used? Can NAudio do that or I must use another midi package tool?

Edit:

OTS Data will contains at least one OTS Track. Each OTS Track has the following structure:

```
byte[0]->byte[3] = 'MTrk' (midi track header of SMF)
byte[4]->byte[7] = 256*256*256*byte[4] + 256*256*byte[5] + 256*byte[6] + byte[7] -> Data length on OTS Track.
byte[8]->byte[n] = SMF data of OTS Track.
```

So, OTS Data will contain this structure at least one time. I will be able to read from each OTS Track, but I don't know which are the C# instructions to achieve those MSB-LSB-PC information from those OTS Track Data SMF data...

Comment: I'm the author of the [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library which allows you to read MIDI data including custom chunks (like OTS). But of course you need to write the code to read your custom chunk by yourself. [Here](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/custom-data-structures/Custom-chunks.html) an example of defining custom chunk so you'll be able to read it. Also can you please provide some sample files with OTS chunk?

Comment: Hi @Maxim. I have edited my question. Please tell me how to use your library to read MSB-LSB-PC of a channel in a SMF?

Comment: To help you I need to know exact format of OTS chunk. Since it's a MIDI chunk, I know its header. But what is in chink content? What is _"SMF data of OTS Track"_? Also I don't know what is _"MSB-LSB-PC"_. Along with format info can you provide a file with OTS chunk? Also you can [create new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/issues/new).

Comment: http://www.wierzba.homepage.t-online.de/stylefiles.htm Here is the file which will explain in details what a style file contains. I need to know (extract) data from OTSc.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/d4ryg390q5qdkqu/LionelRichie_Hello_Amkey_TY.sty Here is a Yamaha Style file which contains that OTSc chunk. I must extract from there all OTS Tracks and for each OTS Track some informations, like program Change (including MSB and LSB for selecting correct voice) Volume, harmony and other data...

Comment: I found some other new information about that chunk. I must study it a bit. A lot of SysEx Messages in there, so I must decode those ones to find my values!

Comment: Right now you should do a lot of work by yourself in your case. **BUT** I did quick tests and I'll try to provide an API in DryWetMIDI that will allow you to read OTS chunk easily. Once I implement that API, I'll post an answer. I suppose I'll do this today or tomorrow. Thanks for sharing your case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to use my [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library. There is the article on the library docs that desctibes how you can define custom chunk class and read its data: [Custom chunks](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/custom-data-structures/Custom-chunks.html).

As for OTS chunk, from links you've provided I see that OTS chunk's data is in fact MIDI file without header chunk. So we can read its content as MIDI file and get the file's track chunks.

Let's define our chunk class:

```
public sealed class OtsChunk : MidiChunk
{
    public const string Id = "OTSc";

    public OtsChunk()
        : base(Id)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrackChunk> TrackChunks { get; private set; }

    protected override void ReadContent(MidiReader reader, ReadingSettings settings, uint size)
    {
        var data = reader.ReadBytes((int)size);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            var midiFile = MidiFile.Read(memoryStream, new ReadingSettings
            {
                NoHeaderChunkPolicy = NoHeaderChunkPolicy.Ignore
            });

            TrackChunks = midiFile.GetTrackChunks().ToArray();
        }
    }

    public override MidiChunk Clone()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override uint GetContentSize(WritingSettings settings)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void WriteContent(MidiWriter writer, WritingSettings settings)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

We won't implement `Clone`, `GetContentSize` and `WriteContent` since you're interested in reading only. (If you want to be able to create such chunks manually and write it to a MIDI file, you will need to implement last two methods too.)

Now we can read Yamaha MIDI file and get OTS chunk:

```
var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("LionelRichie Hello_Amkey_TY.sty", new ReadingSettings
{
    CustomChunkTypes = new ChunkTypesCollection
    {
        { typeof(OtsChunk), OtsChunk.Id }
    }
});

var otsChunk = midiFile.Chunks.OfType<OtsChunk>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you can get regular MIDI events from each track chunk from `otsChunk.TrackChunks`. For example,

```
var firstTrackChunkSysExEvents = otsChunk.TrackChunks.First().Events.OfType<NormalSysExEvent>();
var firstSysExEvent = firstTrackChunkSysExEvents.First();
var firstData = firstSysExEvent.Data;
```

`firstData` will contain bytes of first sys ex event in the first track chunk of OTS chunk. Please note that data will not contain first `F0` byte.

Comment: Thank you @Maxim. Definitely, I will give a try.

Comment: Sorry to post here, but I have no rights to post another question. 
How can I replace a `TrackChunk` in a `CustomChunk`?. So, as you saw, in that OTS I have 4 tracks, which I want to replace, each one with another `TrackChunk`, or even an empty `TruckChunk`. Thanks.

Comment: Can you implement something like `ReplaceChunk(ChunkType oldChunk, ChunkType newChunk)` method? To be able to load a Midi file and to run this little command. MidiChunk will automatically change its size, according to new data ... What do you think about it? Also, RemoveChunk(), EmptyChunk(), RemoveTrack(), EmptyTrack() could be usefull!

Comment: Answered by email.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. Github progress... You are the best!